# 19.10 pip for python 3.8

Tags: python, python3, pip

I have installed python3.8 to python 19.10:

```
 sudo apt install python3.8
```

I now want to install pip for python 3.8

```
 python3.8 -m pip install pip
 Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (18.1)
```

But the pip 3 is **3.7**

```
 pip3 -V
 pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

So that, for example :

```
pip3 install pyinotify
Requirement already satisfied: pyinotify in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.9.6)
```

Attempting to import pyinotify to a python3.8 script throws a `ModuleNotFound` error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sudo apt install python3-pip` or `python3.8-pip` .

Let the system manage your Python version.

---

**Edit**:

The original question was trying to install `pip` via `python -m pip`, and after the original poster used `apt`, the system package manager, instead, they were able to get `pip` working correctly.

As noted in the comments and in [jugmac00](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189877/13247)'s answer, it is now recommended to use `pip` by calling as a Python module:

```
python -m pip install pyinotify
```

If multiple versions of Python are installed on the system and this isn't the default version, you may need to specify the version:

```
python3.8 -m pip install pyinotify
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package python3.8-pip`. There's a `python3-pip` package in ubuntu standard repos, but not `python3.8-pip`, and installing `python3-pip` in an 3.8 environment installs Python 3.6 on the system.

Comment: the answer by jugmac00 works, this does not work

Comment: This answer worked at the time of posting and worked for the original poster.  Things have shifted and accepted answers cannot be deleted. The point remains the same, though... it is best to let the system's package manager manage the python version if possible.

Comment: @earthmeLon I have modified the question to indicate the Ubuntu release that motivated this question. I hope this will clear things up for people encountering your answer.

Answer (score 15):

In order to make sure you are using the correct pip, please use it as follows:

```
python3.8 -m pip install pyinotify
```

Brett Cannon, one of the Python core developers, just recently published a blog article about this topic:
https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

This all said, you usually want to install Python packages into a virtual environment, not in the system Python.

https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: you're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/)?

In a nutshell, it's a good way to test different python versions and you won't have to worry about messing up your system python (projects/installers that make use of the keyword `python`).

1. After installation, open terminal and initialize conda (if you didn't add it to PATH) `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate`
2. Add the channels `intel` and `conda-forge` to find packages there: `conda config --add channels intel && conda config --add channels conda-forge`
3. Create a new environment called py38 with python 3.8 and pip `conda create -n py38 python=3.8 pip`
4. Conda will solve the environment and make sure the packages are compatible. Addressing your initial problem, you can double check the pip version (when I did it, it was `pip-19.3.1-py38_0`
5. Activate your environment `conda activate py38`
6. Now when you type `python` while inside this environment, it will use the interpreter you set up. Also, `pip install` and `conda install` will be directed to your `py38` environment until you `conda deactivate` or switch.

Here's the output when I ran `conda create -n py38 python=3.8 pip`.

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: /home/mikkeyboi/miniconda3/envs/py38
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - pip
>       - python=3.8
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> certifi-2019.9.11          |           py38_0         147 KB  conda-forge
> pip-19.3.1                 |           py38_0         1.9 MB  conda-forge
> python-3.8.0               |       h357f687_3        39.0 MB  conda-forge
> setuptools-41.6.0          |           py38_1         628 KB  conda-forge
> wheel-0.33.6               |           py38_0          35 KB  conda-forge
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:        41.7 MB
> ```
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
>   ca-certificates
>   conda-forge/linux-64::ca-certificates-2019.9.11-hecc5488_0   certifi
>   conda-forge/linux-64::certifi-2019.9.11-py38_0   libffi
>   conda-forge/linux-64::libffi-3.2.1-he1b5a44_1006   libgcc-ng
>   pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0   libstdcxx-ng
>   pkgs/main/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0   ncurses
>   conda-forge/linux-64::ncurses-6.1-hf484d3e_1002   openssl
>   conda-forge/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1d-h516909a_0   pip
>   conda-forge/linux-64::pip-19.3.1-py38_0   python
>   conda-forge/linux-64::python-3.8.0-h357f687_3   readline
>   conda-forge/linux-64::readline-8.0-hf8c457e_0   setuptools
>   conda-forge/linux-64::setuptools-41.6.0-py38_1   sqlite
>   conda-forge/linux-64::sqlite-3.30.1-hcee41ef_0   tk
>   conda-forge/linux-64::tk-8.6.9-hed695b0_1003   wheel
>   conda-forge/linux-64::wheel-0.33.6-py38_0   xz
>   conda-forge/linux-64::xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_1001   zlib
>   conda-forge/linux-64::zlib-1.2.11-h516909a_1006
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages python-3.8.0         | 39.0 MB   |
>
> ############################### | 100%  setuptools-41.6.0    | 628 KB    | ##################################### | 100%  pip-19.3.1
>
> | 1.9 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
>   wheel-0.33.6         | 35 KB     |
>
> ############################### | 100%  certifi-2019.9.11    | 147 KB    | ##################################### | 100%  Preparing
>
> transaction: done Verifying transaction: done Executing transaction:
>   done

I also did `pip install pyinotify` to address your import inquiry, 
`python -c "import pyinotify; print(pyinotify.__version__)"` gave me `0.9.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by myself because I couldn't find a simple way to make this right.

Because of Python3.7 installed first, and Python3.8 is not going to replace old pip when you install it.

Try to look up the location of pip3

```
$ which pip3
```

In my case(macOS), it's located at /usr/local/bin/pip3

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
```

If you installed python3.8 pip properly, you're supposed to see pip3.8

If you do, try to remove it.

```
$ sudo rm pip
```

And copy pip3.8 with a new name, pip3

```
$ sudo cp pip3.8 pip3
```

That's it!!!

I'm not sure is it a perfect solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#get-pip-py) you can try with get-pip.py.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

This will install pip as pip3.8

Answer (score -1):

I had the very same issue. I think the best practice is to call pip from within the python installation, which forces you to be specific on the version of python in which to install the library, ie.

```
python3.8 -m pip install pyinotify
```

Alternatively, you can change the default python installation so that pip3 will refer to python3.8. For managing python versions you can use update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

Now you will have to select the default version. Run the following and press 2

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

pip3 should now refer to your python3.8 package

Comment: **DON'T EVER CHANGE DEFAULT PYTHON!!!** It may cause your system to break and some applications won't even run.

Comment: found it the hard way. I was not aware that my system needs both python2.7 and python3.6 to function. should I delete the comment?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is deletable since at least 20.04 uses Python 3.8 as default Python. You can add warning for users using other releases.